# Partition Start and End Calculation

Tags: partition, disk, fdisk, parted

I was using the **parted** command and i was trying to create a new partition using the **mkpart** option. While i was doing this it asked for the partition **start** and **end**.

Now i believe i know what the **start** and **end** is, the start and end is esentially the starting and the end is just the ending of the partition on the disk or in other words the destination from the start and ending.

So as this happend i dont know how to calculate the start and ending for a new partition, so my question is:

- How do i calculate the **start** and **end?**

Comment: use `print free` to get an idea of where to put partitions, and perhaps `unit mib` for sanity.

Comment: But what would i put for the start and end value for a 30gb partition fot exmaple?

Comment: the start and end is esentially the starting and the end is just the ending of the partition on the disk

Comment: Yes i know but how do i calculate the start/end

Comment: Use `gparted`, it is graphical and easier to use.

Comment: Yes the start is the start, and as you say the end is the end, but what do you mean by destination? They are the location of the partition: Start is the distance from the start of the disk, of the start of the partition. End is the distance from the **start** of the disk, of the end of the partition